# Custom code snippet for WebStorm and PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, code-snippets

I use custom code snippet for *Sublime Text* like custom comments, function, reusable block code, CDN and more.. but I could not do that in WebStorm and PhpStorm IDE.

Here is my building block code snippet (comments) for Sublime Text:

```
 /*============================
            comments
   ============================*/
```

and this code blocks for **HTML5** comments

```
 <!-----------------------
           comments
   ----------------------->
```

Moreover I'm new user for JetBrains software. Can I use custom code snippet above in JetBrains software ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called **Live Templates** in JetBrains IDEs.

Available at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Live Templates`.

You can use existing Live Templates as is, alter them to your needs or create your own.

*Creating own is better be done in own group -- they will be stored in separate config file so easier to share, no possible conflicts with built-in ones (easier to update between versions etc.). It also makes perfect sense to use separate group per language -- the same abbreviation can be used for different languages/context but abbreviation within the same group must be unique.*

*BTW -- I'd say -- do not edit built-ins at all -- just disable specific built-in template and create your own version of it in separate group. This way you can always see what fix/change devs have made in new IDE version etc.*

Full **official tutorial/how-to** is available here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm

---

You may also be interested in other articles:

- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials
- in particular (since you have used Sublime in the past): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+for+Users+of+Text+Editors

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you wanted this.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I get a tips !  PhpStorm allows you to create your own live templates (code snippets) to optimise your workflows.

Open the settings dialog and head into **Editor | Live Templates**, you can see the available live templates grouped by language. To add a new template click the + (plus) button and select Live Template. Specify the abbreviation (the short bit of text you type that will be expanded to the full code snippet) and a description.

Then provide the full code snippet in the Template text field. You can include variables in the template in the format `$<variable name>$`, which will allow you to provide values when the template is expanded. PhpStorm recognises `$END$` as a special variable indicating the final position of the cursor after the template has been expanded and values have been provided for all variables.

Next click the Define warning text to specify which language the template is for and optionally the context it is available in.

Now the template is ready to be used. Open a file and type the abbreviation that was specified earlier, then hit Tab to expand the template. The cursor will be positioned on the first variable, provide a value then hit Tab to keep moving through all available variables. The final position of the cursor will be the location of the `$END$` variable.

[image]

Further Reading

- [Creating & Editing Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this, however you can add custom tags in **Settings > Editor > TODO**.

`//TODO` & `//FIXME` are already implemented.

But this custom tags are not working for HTML.

Maybe you can find an extension to do that in **Settings > Plugins**.

Comment: So **TODO** means  todo /task list ?

Comment: In your code you can add //TODO and write something after this. Same for //FIXME. All of those will be listed in the "TODO" tab bottom left. Then in settings you can do custom tags like //REVIEW, or what you want/need. So yes, it can be a task list.

Comment: You can also use this : [JetBrains Custom Regions Comments](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/folding-custom-regions-with-line-comments.html)

Comment: Its helpful for me ! therefor, it would be better if i can made custom code snippet